# Openvpn Route internet through one client

Tags: router, internet, openvpn

I have client A and client B connected to OpenVpn Acess Sever. In AS i have "allow internet through vpn" disabled.  How can i route internet through vpn for Client A only? Client B should not pass internet traffic through VPN.

Answer (score 1):

enable "allow internet through vpn" in the AS and in the client you dont want to redirect the traffic through the vpn put this at the end of the conf file

```
route 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 64.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 128.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 192.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
```

that's it tells you client machine not to use the vpn as internet connection then that machine it will be connected to the vpn but it will be using the local internet

Comment: 192.0.0.0 is the gw right?

Comment: yes just as it is and it will work try it and tell me ;)

Comment: there is another way to get the same result but honestly i dont remember how do you have to search it !

Comment: I enabled internet via vpn. Client A &B had internet via VPN. On client B (openwrt) I put the routes in my .ovpn file. Yes I was not connected to internet via VPN but I could not see client A which is on the 10.10.10.0 subnet.  Before routes I could get from Client B to Client A , no problem. Any help?

Comment: If you have client to client set into the server there should not be a problem maybe something whit a firewall !